# TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, pygame-surface

Please help. I've been searching but i still don't quite grasp how to fix the problem. I don't know if i;m forgetting something or the values of x and y are not considered int's for some reason (i have put in past tries to fix it: int(x))

I want to create the dinosaur game from Google, but the .blit of the "Hidrante" class is failing (but the player one is functioning). I have put it normal values instead of self.x and self.y but still get the problem, i've tried to said it x and y are ints, tried to change the names, the image i'm loading, and replicate the code of the player but doesn't seem to work.

here is all the code

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))

pygame.display.set_caption("Dinosaurio")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
char = pygame.image.load('dino.png')
bg = pygame.image.load('bg2.jpg')
img = pygame.image.load("H2.jpg")


class Player(object):
#values of player
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 30, 64)
#putting the player on screem
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(char, (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 30, 64)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)

#Obstacle
class Hidrante(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self. height = height
        self.vel = 8
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        self.walkCount = 10
        self.path = 0
#putting the obstacle in screem
    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33: #fill code, trying things not actual util
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y)) #here is the problem
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y))#these too
            self.walkCount += 1
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 30, 60)  
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)


def gmv():
#putting on creem the objects
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    dino.draw(window)
    hidrante.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()

#creating the objects
dino = Player(110, 620, 64, 64)
hidrante = Hidrante(1100, 620, 64, 64)
run = True
neg = 1
while run:
    clock.tick(30) #frames
    hidrante.x = (hidrante.x ** 2) * -1 #Function to not jump infinit.

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False
#Space to jump
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if not (dino.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            dino.isJump = True
    else:
        if dino.jumpCount >= -10:
            dino.y -= (dino.jumpCount * abs(dino.jumpCount)) * 0.5
            dino.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            dino.jumpCount = 10
            dino.isJump = False

    gmv()


pygame.quit()
```

i've only want to know the reason why the values of object are interfering with .blit and learn how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates which are passed to [`pygame.Surface.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) have to be in a certain limit.
It seems that the limit for a coordinate has to be within the range of the ([`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)) data type `int`, which is from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

You exceed this limit in the object `hidrante`, because of the line:

> ```py
> hidrante.x = (hidrante.x ** 2) * -1
> ```

Probably this formula doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Anyway, validate if `hidrante.x` is in bounds of thee screen, to solve the issue:

```py
class Hidrante(object):

    # [...]

        def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33: #fill code, trying things not actual util
            self.walkCount = 0

        # validate if object is in the window
        if self.x > -30 and self.x < 1000:

            if self.vel > 0:
                window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 30, 60)  
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)
```